# Automatic onsubmit handler in loop

Tags: javascript, handler, onsubmit

I have the following problem with Javascript.
I'm trying to add an "onsubmit" handler automatically (after the page has been loaded) to every form element in the page.
So I wrote this script:

```
window.onload=function(){
    var formElements=document.getElementsByTagName("form");
    for (var k=0;k<formElements.length;k++){
        formElements[k].onsubmit=function(param){
            return formValidator(param);
        }(formElements[k]);
    }
};
```

The formValidator function takes a form object as parameter, validates the content of the input and textarea elements inside the form and returns true or false as results of the validation.
In the HTML file of the page I have a form element without the onsubmit attribute (that should be inserted by javascript).

The problem is that it seems that the form is automatically validated when the page is loaded (even if the user doesn't submit the form). And then if the user starts to insert data in the form and clicks the submit button the validateForm function doesn't execute.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're **calling** your handler function, and assigning the result of calling it to `onsubmit`. (The `(formElements[k])` after the function calls it.)

You need to *refer* to the function without calling it. One good way to do that in the general case is to use a builder function (but see below for why that general case probably doesn't apply here):

```
window.onload=function(){
    var formElements=document.getElementsByTagName("form");
    for (var k=0;k<formElements.length;k++){
        formElements[k].onsubmit=buildHandler(formElements[k]);
    }

    function buildHandler(form) {
        return function(){
            return formValidator(form); // <== I'm guessing `formvalidator` takes the form
        };
    }
};
```

But there's no need to create a separate handler for each form. The way you're assigning the handler, `this` will be the `form` element, so just:

```
window.onload=function(){
    var formElements=document.getElementsByTagName("form");
    for (var k=0;k<formElements.length;k++){
        formElements[k].onsubmit=handler;
    }

    function handler(){
        return formValidator(this);
    }
};
```

The thing about `this` being the element will be true when you assign functions to `onxyz` properties on DOM elements, when you use `attachEvent` (on IE), or when you use `addEventListener` (standard). It is **not** true if you call a function from `onxyz` **attributes** in the markup, e.g. `onsubmit="foo()"` (although you can use `onsubmit="foo.call(this);"` and it will be).

Comment: thank you very much for replying so fast. Your code works great but I admit that I'm not so sure why it works. Tell if I'm wrong: in my code the function formValidator was actually executed and the return value (true or false) was assigned to the onsubmit attribute of the form. Did I understand right?

Comment: @condorwasabi: Yes, that's right. Leaving out specifics, you had `onsubmit = function() {...}();`. The parens at the end **call** the function in front of them and the expression's result is the function's return value (exactly like `onsubmit = foo();` would). You want `onsubmit = function() {...};` instead (no `()`). In the above, we just use the function reference without calling it. The first example calls `buildHandler`, which returns a function (in order to close over the element), and in the second of course we're fairly clearly not doing any call in that expression.